# Conformal weight of one dimensional scalar fields

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

In string theory a conformal transformation changes the metric, $g_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow \Omega(\tau, \sigma)g_{\mu\nu}$ with $g_{\mu\nu}$ the two-dimensional metric on the (Polyakov) string worldsheet. It otherwise leaves the bosonic fields alone, $X^{\mu}(\tau, \sigma) \rightarrow X^{\mu}(\tau, \sigma)$.

**Q1: Is this because the bosonic fields have conformal weight $\mathbb{0}$?**

Now to follow up how does this work in point particle theory. Can we form a conformally invariant theory using an action of the form
$$S = -\int e^{-1}(\tau) \dot{X}^{2} - m^{2}e(\tau) d\tau$$
by setting $m^{2} = 0$, having the einbein $e$ transform as the square root of a metric determinant and choosing $X^\mu(\tau)$ to have the right conformal weight?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): It seems OP is conflating [conformal & Weyl transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38138/2451).