# Deriving Klein-Gordon equation in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I try to drive The Klein-Gordon equation for a massless scalar field in case of FRW metric:

$$
ds^2= a^2(t) [-dt^2 + dx^2]
$$

So I start by:

$$\left(\frac{1}{g^{1/2}}\partial_{\mu}(g^{1/2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}) \right)\phi = 0$$

The determinant of the metric is $(\sqrt{-g}=a^4)$. So that the equation leads to:

\begin{eqnarray} \nonumber
&&\frac{1}{a^4} \left( \partial_0 a^4 g^{0\nu} \partial_\nu + \partial_i a^4 g^{i\nu} \partial_\nu   \right) \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&& \partial_0 a^4 g^{00} \partial_0  \phi +  a^4 g^{ij} \partial_i \partial_j  \phi=0,\\ \nonumber
&& - \partial_0 a^2 \partial_0  \phi +  a^4 \nabla^2   \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&& - 2 a \dot{a} \dot{\phi} -  a^2  \ddot{\phi} +  a^4 \nabla^2 \phi =0,\\
&&  2 \frac{ \dot{a}}{a^3} \dot{\phi} +  \frac{1}{a^2}  \ddot{\phi} -  \nabla^2 \phi=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Please let me know if this derivation is correct.

Comment: *Please let me know if this derivation is correct.* Check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site, so your post may get closed.

Comment: You’ve written the metric in a way that makes it look like you are working in 2D spacetime, which I don’t think you’re actually doing.

Comment: Klein-Gordon equation with non-zero mass: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748626/

Comment: @TheTiler. Thanks for the link. The Klein-Gordon equation is given in this thread by $\ddot{\phi} + 2\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\dot{\phi} - \Delta \phi + m^2a^2\phi = 0$ for the same metric, but I wonder why there is a difference a factor $\frac{1}{a^2}$ from my result.

Comment: The $\Delta$ in the other answer is the Laplacian w.r.t. $\delta_{ij}$. The $\nabla^2$ you are using is w.r.t. the metric $g_{ij} = a^2 \delta_{ij}$. Consequently, $\nabla^2= \frac{1}{a^2} \Delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I soppuse that the answer should be

\begin{eqnarray} \nonumber
&&\frac{1}{a^4} \left( \partial_0 a^4 g^{0\nu} \partial_\nu + \partial_i a^4 g^{i\nu} \partial_\nu   \right) \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&& \partial_0 a^4 g^{00} \partial_0  \phi +  a^4 g^{ij} \partial_i \partial_j  \phi=0,\\ \nonumber
&& (\partial_0 a^4) g^{00} \partial_0  \phi+ a^4(\partial_0 g^{00}) \partial_0  \phi   +a^4 g^{00} \partial^2_0  \phi+  a^4 \nabla^2   \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&& 4 a^3 \dot{a} (-a^{-2}) \partial_0  \phi+ a^4 (2 a^{-3} \dot{a}) \partial_0  \phi +a^4 (-a^{-2}) \ddot{\phi}  +  a^4 \nabla^2   \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&& -4 a \dot{a} \dot {\phi}+2 a \dot{a} \dot{\phi}  -a^2 \ddot{\phi} +a^4   \nabla^2   \phi=0, \\ \nonumber
&&  2 \frac{ \dot{a}}{a^3} \dot{\phi} +  \frac{1}{a^2}  \ddot{\phi} -  \nabla^2 \phi=0.
\end{eqnarray}
so I believe it is fine

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GabrielPalau.

Comment: I just wonder why in that thread https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/748626/klein-gordon-equation-in-frw-spacetime. there is a difference a factor $\frac{1}{a^2}$ from my result.

Comment: In the other question there is a conformal transformation:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612945/is-conformal-transformation-a-coordinate-transformation-or-not